# How to use Mapreduce to analyse a review data file with just Review and Rating data column

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to come up with a mapreduce code to produce the most common Product mentioned in the reviews and its corresponding rating, I am quite new to Hadoop and it would be great if anyone can guild me on this.

Following is the data structure I have got, it has two fields Review Details and Rating, The product name is mentioned in the review details itself and there is no separated field for Product name Or Id. The rating is also added to the column next to the review. Also need to emit common words such as (the, and, it) etc.

```
Review Details | Rating
"The Nokia 3310 is one of my favorite mobile phones and the new phone makes me happy"   | 7
"Talking about phone there is nothing else than Apple comes to my mind, the I phone 7 is the best in market"    | 9
"Samsung J7 doesn’t live up to the expectations and its not worthy for the price"   | 1
"I am not a Big fan of I Phone 7, opt for something cheaper and save money" | 3
```

Comment: If you have no "list of products" ahead of time. This isn't possible. For example, what says that "I Phone 7"  is a product rather than "Apple"?

Comment: I need to extract I Phone 7, Nokia 3310, Samsung J7 and their average rating. I hope it is possible with the above dataset?

Comment: I understand what you want, but what if you had another review that included "Google Pixel"? How would your code "know" that is a product? Besides, StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, so do a word-count yourself and see if you can get close.

Comment: Yeh a word count will give me the number of times a particular word was mentioned in the reviews. Then can I use that word as a key to get average ratings ?

Comment: Well, that'll be difficult for "I Phone 7", which is seen as three words